# Почему не получается создать новый выпуск в Google Console?

Tags: unity3d, google-play, unity3d-android, google-console

Не понимаю в чём причина. 5 января загружал новое приложение, всё нормально. Сейчас решил обновить старое (2 месяца назад последний раз) и выдаёт вот это:
Вы загрузили APK-файл или набор Android App Bundle с объектом activity, псевдонимом объекта, сервисом или широковещательным приемником с фильтром intent, но без набора свойств android:exported. Этот файл нельзя установить на устройство с версией Android 12 или выше. Чтобы узнать больше, перейдите на developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported.
Добавлял в файл манифеста строку, о которой говорится на сайте, но это ничего не дало. Та же ошибка.
Что делать?

Манифест файл:

По этому пути: Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml
Дописал строчку о которой говорилось в статье: android:exported="true", но та же ошибка.

````
<!-- GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN-->
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:exported="true"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>```



Помогите, прошу. Пробовал по разному уже. И true, и false, но не хочет.
````

Comment: Аналогичная ситуация. Последний раз загружал новую версию приложения 11 января. С 13 января при загрузке новой версии Google Play Console выдаёт ту же ошибку, что и у вас. Заметил, что в директории project_root\Temp\StagingArea во время сборки Unity создаёт сгенерированный манифест AndroidManifest.xml, и в нём независимо от того, что было указано в Custom Manifest, этой строки (android:exported) нет.

Comment: Вам ещё нужна помощь? Смог решить проблему

Comment: Я сделал откат до 30 апи, теперь ошибки при загрузке отсутствуют. Надеюсь, что в скором времени в юнити добавят совместимость с новыми апи.

Answer (score 1):

Ребят, я потратил много времени на устранение проблемы, но таки решил её.
Нужно изменить API с API 32 до API 30 -
Это устранит ошибку при загрузке .aab в GooglePlay.

Но при билдинге .aab файла в юнити у меня вышла другая ошибка...

> WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated. It
> will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.

и ещё ошибка

> Warning: Mapping new ns
> http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns
> http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01 FAILURE: Build
> failed with an exception.
> What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> Installed Build Tools revision 32.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

так вот вместо того чтобы устранять первую ошибку
и ставить галочку в Publishing Settings - Custom Base Gradle Template и вносить изменения в кастомные файлы baseProjectTemplate.gradle
(Всё это делать было не нужно! т.к. Ошибки не уйдут.)

Нужно было обратить внимание на вторую ошибку которая "Installed Build Tools revision 32.0.0 is corrupted"
сдесь вам поможет - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387270/android-studio-error-installed-build-tools-revision-31-0-0-is-corrupted user16475264

И у меня всё сбилдилось без галочек и кастомных файлов, но только на API30.
Я счастлив!

Answer (score 0):

Открой AndroidManifest.xml и проверь наличие в библиотеках android:exported = true если их нет обнови библиотеку.

Comment: где найти этот androidmanifest ?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что я поставил самый высокий Target API (32), он появился недавно. Кастомный манифест в этом случае никак не помогает, по всей видимости юнити ещё не доделала это.
Минимальный апи может быть 30 и с ним при загрузке проблем нет.

Answer (score 0):

В окне `Build Settings` включи галочку `Export Project`, затем кнопку `Build`, и выбери папку, куда будет помещен android проект. После сборки перейди в эту папку, далее `unityLibrary\src\main` и там будет лежать `AndroidMainfest.xml`. Проверь, все ли активности и ресиверы имеют `android:exported`, если нет, то пробуй обновить нужные бтблиотеки.

В моем случае нужно было обновить пакет `Mobile Notifications` в окне `Package Manager`

Answer (score 0):

android:exported="false"> может ты забыл добавить в конце >. Вопрос задан 7 месяцев назад, но может кто-то тоже забыл добавить >.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос